# How to stop phpunit after an arbitrary number of failures

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, phpunit

Some background first:  I've written some selenium tests to hit some of our internal web sites and check for errors.  At the moment these tests are finding quite a few bugs, which is good--I want these tests to run automatically every 6 hours or so, and email my team the results of the test, serving as inspiration to fix all of these errors we have.  However, I also don't really want phpunit to email 999999 errors to everyone every 6 hours.  I'd like the number of errors to be more reasonable, like, say, 20 at a time.

So, my question is:  Is there a way to stop phpunit after X failures?  I know you can stop it after 1 failure using --stop-on-failure, but I want it to stop after any arbitrary number of failures.

I can think of a way to accomplish this by throwing failures as exceptions, then keeping a static variable that counts the number of exceptions, etc, but it seems hacky and unnecessary.  Does anyone know of a better way to do it?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a PHPUnit Test Listener that will count the number of errors and failures detected, using a static variable.

Then when the errors threshold is reached your best bet will be probably throw an Exception on the startTest method of the listener, so no other tests will be executed, but I haven't checked that.

Links to the relevant PHPUnit docs sections:

[Example of creating a Test Listener.](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener)

[Enabling the test listener in the XML config file.](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.test-listeners)

Comment: Excellent answer thanks.  The full set of steps I had to take were:
1)  Create a listener class that listened for failures, by copy-pasting from your test listener link, then altering the class so it would keep a static count of failures via the required addFailure method.
2)  Alter my phpunit.xml config file to specify the listener to use, which I pointed at the class I defined in #1
3)  Add a setUp() function to the class I wanted to stop running tests after so many failures.  setUp() just called the class in #1.

This method more pre-fails things than stops phpunit, but close enough.